# How to rig a chest lid

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigging, bones

I have never made any rigs or used bones before, but I need to do an extremely simple task. I have modeled a chest, and I simply want to rig it so that I can open and close it with a click and drag of the mouse. Here's the chest:

[image]

And I want it to open like this (in this case I'm using R+Y with 3D cursor at pivot point)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possibility:

1. Add a bone that begins in the rotation axis. Any other object will do as well because I don't use a rig but simply a parent/child.
   [image]
2. Parent the bone to the top of the chest and the bottom of the chest to the bone.
   [image]
3. Lock the location of the bone and two of the rotation axes (depends on how your bone is rotated).

[image]

Now you can select the bone and press R to open and close the chest independent of the chests position or rotation.

[image]

Note that you don't even need a third object for that (bone). If the top's origin is on the rotation axis then you can parent directly and lock position as well as two rotation axes.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. It will help others find the solution to their own problems and give proper credit to the one that answered it.